# Не работает Ajax-вызов

Tags: ajax

Код не выдает ошибок, но и не выполняется. (Это из учебника пример)

```
<!-- urlpost.html -->
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Пример использования Ajax </title>
    </head>

    <body><center />
    <h1>Загрузка веб-страницы в контейнер DIV</h1>
    <div id="info"> Это предложение будет заменено </div>

    <script>

    params = "url=oreilly.com"
    request = new ajaxRequest()
    request.open("POST", "urlpost.php", true)
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)   
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")

    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(this.readyState == 4)
        {
            if(this.status == 200)
            {
                if(this.responseText != null)
                {
                    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 
                    this.responseText
                }
                else alert("Ошибка Ajax: Данные не получены")
            }
        else alert("Ошибка Ajax: " + this.statusText)
        }
    }

    request.send(params)

    function ajaxRequest()
    {
        try // Для всех браузеров, кроме ие
        {
            var request = new XMLHTTPRequest()
        }
        catch(e1)
        {
            try // ие6+
            {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
            }
            catch(e2)
            {
                try // ie5
                {
                    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                }
                catch(e3) // Браузер не поддерживает Ajax
                {
                    request = false
                }
            }
        }
    return request
    }

    </script></body></html>
```

Файл пхп

```
    <?php //urlpost.php
    if(isset($_POST['url']))
        {
            echo file_get_content("http://".SanitazeString($_POST['url']));
        }

        function SanitazeString($var) {
        $var = strip_tags($var);
        $var = htmlentities($var);
        return stripslashes($var);
        }

?>
```

Что с ним неправильно?

Comment: @Heidel, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Ну а по существу вопроса что-нибудь?

Comment: @Heidel Пишу сюда, лимит комментариев. Вы странно копируете код))

Не `XMLHTTPRequest`, a `XMLHttpRequest` =)

Comment: А, да, действительно, пропустила, это потому что не копировала, а так исправляла)) Большое спасибо, всё работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу вижу:

1) нет точек с запятой между операторами (это не всегда страшно, но это быдлокод)

2) в .php и .js - Функцию надо объявлять перед тем, как вызвать) они не компилируются и нельзя использовать функцию/переменную/что угодно до объявления.

Исправленная функция:

```
function ajaxRequest() {
  var r;
  try {
    r=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch(e) {
    try {
      r = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        r = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      } catch (e) {
          r = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}

// использование: var request = ajaxRequest(); // без new!
```

Comment: А, ну это вообще первая книжка по теме, кторую я читаю, там точек с запятой в скриптах нигде нет.
Если поставить функции перевд их вызовом, то ничего не изменится.

Comment: > Если поставить функции перевд их вызовом, то ничего не изменится.

Да ладно? А попробовать?)

А еще загляните в консоль ошибок JS (у фаерфокса это ctrl+shift+j)

Comment: Не, ну так я попробовала, вот и говорю, что ничего не измениться.
Консоль ошибок внезапно говорит, что request.open is not a function, и чего с этим делать?

Comment: .

    //params = "url=oreilly.com"
    //request = new ajaxRequest()
    function ajaxRequest() {
      // код функции
    }
    var params = "url=oreilly.com";
    var request = ajaxRequest();
    if (request) {
      // весь остальной код
    } else alert('Ошибка: Ваш браузер не поддерживает AJAX');

Comment: А теперь выводится ошибка alert("Ошибка: Ваш браузер не поддерживает AJAX"), то есть, получается, что request = 0. Это из-за чего?

Comment: Вот исправленный код http://jsfiddle.net/AjKvp/, вроде всё что вы сказали, я поправила.

Comment: в js - Функцию надо объявлять перед тем, как вызвать?..
Открываем JS консоль, пишем:

    a()
    function a() {}

С т.з. JS данное высказывание справедливо только для анонимной функции, т.е. код вида

    a()
    var a = function(){}

Выдаст ошибку, но код выше ее не выдаст

они не компилируются - тоже кстати не совсем верно

Comment: @AlexWindHope и тем не менее этот стиль убог и нелогичен, а новичкам лучше привыкать к нормальному коду сразу. 
Ну и php точно не компилируется, js - если только в рантайме, не вдавался в такие подробности (википедия говорит, что может интерпретироваться, транслироваться в байт-код явы или компилиться в рантайме - компиляции в обычном понимании здесь все равно нет).

Comment: @Sh4dow - это нормальный стиль, он может позволить привести код к такому виду, что он будет хорошо читаться сверху вниз, не смотря на свою асинхронную натуру из обработчиков событий, при этом не порождая спагетти кода из колбеков.

Более того - какая разница плохой это стиль или хороший? Вы утверждаете что **этого вообще сделать нельзя**.

По поводу компиляции - что значит в обычном понимании? Вы написали что ее **вообще нет**, ни в каком понимании.

И того - абсолютно абсурдный ответ с 2умя неверными пунктами, посему и минуснул.

Comment: Ну ладно с javascript вы не так глубоко знакомы, но PHP же, как я раньше думал, знаете, не знать того, что функцию можно вызывать до ее объявления, это, простите, стыдно =)

ну и для особо ленивых, либо неверующих - [пруф](http://codepad.org/Wj5Z7rIc)

Comment: Ну я могу только повторить, что такой стиль убог, ибо порождает хаос (вместо привычного взгляда наверх надо искать эту функкцию по всему коду) - потому им пользоваться не надо. Будут огромные дыры в коде и карме. 

    LOL:
    //test(1); function test() { alert('lol'); } //ok
    //test(1); if (1) function test() { alert('lol'); } //error
    // я не хочу работать с таким адом. "потому что на--я" (с)

Слова "вообще" там не было. Имелось в виду отсутствие типичного для компилируемых ("транслирющих в отдельный файл машинный код" для юристов) языков отложенного объявления, но раз так - пардон.

Comment: @Sh4dow с т.з. PHP это действительно плохой стиль, с т.з. JavaScript - абсолютно нормальный (это на заметку).

По поводу компиляции - кэп бессилен